# Deleting Semi Duplicate Rows in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have rows in my table that needs deleting based on a few columns being duplicates.

e.g Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4

If Col1,Col2 and Col3 are duplicates regardless of what value is in Col4 I want both these duplicates deleted. How do I do this?

Comment: Add some sample table data, before and after "duplicates deleted".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the `where` clause:

```
delete from t
    where (col1, col2, col3) in (select col1, col2, col3
                                 from t
                                 group by col1, col2, col3
                                 having count(*) > 1
                                );
```

Answer (score 3):

Group by these IDs and check with HAVING whether there are duplicates. With the duplicates thus found delete the records.

```
delete from mytable 
where  (col1,col2,col3) in
(
  select col1,col2,col3
  from mytable 
  group by col1,col2,col3
  having count(*) > 1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS` to remove a row if another row with same col1, col2 and col3 exists with a lower col4 value. I.e keep one col1, col2, col3 row.

```
delete from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t2.col1 = t1.col1
                and t2.col2 = t1.col2
                and t2.col3 = t1.col3
                and t2.col4 < t1.col4)
```

To remove both/all rows, skip the col4 condition, do a `group by` instead:

```
delete from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t2.col1 = t1.col1
                and t2.col2 = t1.col2
                and t2.col3 = t1.col3
              group by t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3
              having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: . . "I want both these duplicates deleted".